# Php-fpm installed but php info still show CGI

Tags: nginx, centos, web-server, php-fpm

I have a centos 7 server with a cwp installation on it (I have installed on it apache/nginx/varnish).

i installed php-fpm and the status confirm it's running

```
php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since ven 2020-03-20 01:12:59 CET; 13h ago
 Main PID: 19317 (php-fpm)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 5, Requests: 0, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service
           ├─19317 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─19318 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─19319 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─19320 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─19321 php-fpm: pool www
           └─19322 php-fpm: pool www
```

but if I go to php-info() page, in the voice server api instead of showing FCGI/FastCGI it shows CGI/FastCGI. What can be the error?

i have php 7.3.15 and Nginx/1.16.1

Comment: Since you've got both apache and nginx, which of the two serves you the php-info page?  Then show us the configuration of that server, where you've linked to php-fpm instead of cgi.

Comment: I don't know much about it, I followed this guide. Which conf file should I show? https://noviello.it/come-installare-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lamp-su-centos-7/
i even tried to create the page info.php in my Nginx/html folder but it doesn't show up, it's like my server it's still using apache as main webserver, how can I check?

Comment: Only your varnish config can tell you: when it receives a request on port 80, does it send it to Apache or to Nginx?   Varnish could even answer itself, if it has that page cached.

Comment: noviello.it never mentions Varnish or Apache, why did you mix those with nginx?

Comment: actually I'm using centos web panel, and I used Novello guide just for installing and configuring php-fpm ( and also done the Nginx conf file as in the guide )

Comment: I tried to switch cwp to "Nginx only" and phpinfo() says CLI for server api... ignoring fpm. but if I check fpm status is active and running... I guess somewhere I'm missing something somewhere to let Nginx know to use fpm... but I did add the value in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Comment: Normallly, Varnish would be the frontend on your server, as reverse proxy for Apache.  Did you change your Varnish configuration so that it knows it has to send some requests to Nginx?

Comment: no, haven't touched varnish yet. it's installed but disabled

Comment: If I were you, I'd restart on a clean system, and install only one webserver, either Apache or Nginx.

Comment: at first any question which have a administrative control panel installed are out of scope, second none private questions are allowed. Please use superuser as you seem not to have the ability as an administrator would have the knowledge